# Stateful Angular's services

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive, that needs a data to be loaded from the server. The data depends on *id*, and for each instance of directive it will be different.

I think it will be better to write the logic of downloading the data in a *service*, that than will be injected in directive. But with plain Angular's services, that are singletons, i will have one and the same data for all instances of directive.

In the internet i found that in the service i can write a method, that will return a new instance of object, and than use it.

My questions are:

1. Is it normal to write such a logic in services?
2. What should i do with service for my purposes?

Comment: I think factories might be helful in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused by the definition of "singleton" in this context. It's what other languages call "shared" or "static" function; as opposed to "member" function. So you will call the same function - but you won't get the same data back. You can have service definition with `$http` or `$resource` or whatever; but then if you invoke this service from the controller (or from the directive - I just never had a need to do that), you pass `id` as parameter, and get the result that you want.

The bottom line, service returns a function (and this function is a singleton, that is, same function application-wide); but then you call this function with parameters and get the result that you want